# How can I get a unique CSS Selector for a DOM element given the element's value?

Tags: javascript, node.js, dom

Let's say I have the following document:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello world</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

Given the string "Hello world", how can I search the document and generate a CSS Selector for the correct element(in this case, the h1)?

Comment: `:contains('Hello world')`

Comment: You'd have to use jQuery. There is no way using standard css: https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors

Answer (score 2):

Okay, that was sloppy -- if you use $(":contains"), you get the entire tree down to the innermost element. Using this, you find the innermost node.

```js
var myContainer = $(":contains('Hello world') ");

while(myContainer.children().length != 0) {
    myContainer =myContainer.children();
}
myContainer.addClass("foo");
```

```css
.foo {
  border: 1px dotted blue;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello world</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

Or, to do the same thing with a single selector:

```js
$(":contains('Hello world'):not(:has(*))").addClass("foo");
```

```css
.foo {
  border: 1px dotted blue;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content-pane">
<div class="header-pane">
<h1>Hello world</h1>
</div>
<div class="inner-content">
<h2>
Hello world is me!
</h2>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a pure javascript answer without using a library you could use DOM manipulation/traversal.

I have adapted this code snippet that is designed to traverse a node tree and return the text contents as a string. https://gist.github.com/padolsey/3033511

```
function getText(node) {

if (node.nodeType === 3) {
    return node.data;
}

var txt = '';

if (node = node.firstChild) do {
    txt += getText(node);
} while (node = node.nextSibling);

return txt;
```

}

```js
function checkNode(node) {

  if (node.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
    var expr= "Hello World";
    if (node.textContent.indexOf(expr) >= 0) {
      node.parentNode.className = "foo";
    }
  }

  if (node = node.firstChild) {
    //set to next child and continue if it exists
    do {
      checkNode(node);
    } while (node = node.nextSibling); //while has sibilings
}

}
checkNode(document.body)
```

```css
.foo {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>

  <h1>Hello World</h1>

  <p>Hello World</p>

  <h1>Hlelo Wrldo</h1>

</div>
```

I came up with this solutions after some research leading me to this blog post from James Padolsey: [Replacing text in the DOM… solved?](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/replacing-text-in-the-dom-solved/) He talks about the difficulties of traversing elements to accurately get the text they contain because the text shown to the user may be spread over a couple child elements like this:

```
<p>
  This is a <span class="f">te<em>st</em></span>.
</p>
```

The main topic of that blog post is replacing the text and he has created a very good example of how to do so while respecting strange nesting as shown above. If you are interested in a much more robust solution without including a library I suggest giving his post a read. It is somewhat old but his example at the end works and is also based off the same gist I provided.